# Can't change folder ownership via SSH

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, sudo, permissions

For some reason, I have a folder that I cannot read nor change its ownership.
If I do a ls command, this is what I get:

```
drwxrwxrwx  4 myusername myusername 4096 Jan 26 20:35 media1 <--- OK
drwxrwxrwx  4 myusername myusername 4096 Jan 26 20:35 media2 <--- OK
drwxrwxrwx  4 myusername apache   4096 Jan 26 20:35 media3 <--- CANNOT READ
```

From what I see, it is the 4th column the problem, which is different from the other ones. I tried different commands (chown, chgrp) with sudo privileges, but with no luck.

What do I have to do to make its permissions like the other folders (media1, media2)?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo chown -R myusername:myusername media3`

Should do the trick. The -R stands for recursive, and will make your username and group combo (first part is username, second part is group name) own the entire folder and its contents.